# @react-navigation/drawer vs react-navigation-drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer

Are the following two imports for react navigation drawer equivalent?

React native docs at [React Navigation 5.x Drawer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/) uses the second form of Import.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import for version 2.5.2 check npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-drawer

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```

Second import for version 5 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-navigation/drawer

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
```

Finder with @react-navigation/drawer in node-modules
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if I am using React Navigation 5.x in react-native app then only the second form of Import is needed. Is that correct?